# Sort Object by its value and get key as the output in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Say I have an object like:

```
{A:5, B:3, C:-7, D:0}
```

I want to get an Array of its keys in asec/desc order like:

```
['C','D','B','A']
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply sort the keys, with [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with the difference between the values of the corresponding keys, like this

```
console.log(Object.keys(data).sort(function(a, b) {
    return data[a] - data[b];
}));
# [ 'C', 'D', 'B', 'A' ]
```

To sort in the reverse order, simply find the difference between the values of `b` and `a`, like this

```
console.log(Object.keys(data).sort(function(a, b) {
    return data[b] - data[a];
}));
# [ 'A', 'B', 'D', 'C' ]
```

Comment: Awesome, that's so neat!

Answer (score 1):

use `Object.keys(obj)` which gives an array that you can then sort on the keys using whatever ordering you like.